# How do you cancel a timed system halt?

Tags: terminal

as the title says "How do you cancel a timed system halt" is there any CL for that? just like in window's run shutdown.exe -a for canceling a timed shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown), you can run `shutdown -c` (prepend `sudo` to grant root access).

Please note that it obviously won't work when `shutdown` is called with `now` as time parameter (`shutdown now`).